# Web service JSON representation / editing

Tags: javascript, json, web, editor

everyone!

I want to create a web-based service that will be able to craft a JSON file in a specific predefined format.

JSON will consist of a specific sections, and each section will contain a list of rules, which user should be able to add \ remove \ edit in a user-friendly manner (e.g. define a true \ false value for a rule with a checkbox, add a new rule with + button under the last rule, etc).
In the end user should be able to download the final JSON file.

I have python development background, and just starting writing in JS, and my questions to you guys are:

- How and where do I store the current state of JSON file between pages
  switches?
- Any particular advice how to organize addition \ removal of
  elements and corresponding JSON changes?
- General advice to a newbie JS developer for this task?

Thank you, boys and girls, this is my first question on SO, hope community can help me!

Comment: I will guide you throught, let's connect on whatsapp +91 9998410545

Comment: JSON is used for data exchange. If you want to manipulate the data you should use `JSON.parse` to transform the data into an object. The object can reside on the cilent. `JSON.stringify` will turn your object back into a JSON string.